# How set width of one element equal to other in android?

Tags: android

I have two buttons defined in XML

```
 <Button
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/takepic_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Take_Pic"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"           
     />


     <Button
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="right"    
     />
```

My question is how can I tell android that set the width of second button equal to whatever is the width of first button.

Update: I am looking for XML solution

Comment: in the XML currently I am doing `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` instead of this I want to set width equal to first button

Comment: sorry then.. my answer is in appropriate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the android:layout_weight properties set to the same value for both of your button.

```
<Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 />


 <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);     
        int i=btn1.getWidth();
        btn2.setWidth(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If in code.. just do

```
button2.set(button1.getWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

In xml for two buttons sideby side in a horizontal layout use

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

hope this helps